# How to Display Two or more Css loader in one html page

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to put and display Two or more Css loader **With different   proprieties** in one HTML Page

First spinner Need To be spin **90** Degree *Work perfectly* 
second spinner Need To be spin **360** Degree but the output of it is Duplicated of  ***First spinner***

I try This From W3SC [Loader](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp)
then modified it and named it **Double Loader.html**

I want to make first loader spin in 90 degree 
and the other loader spin in 360 degree

HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>A 90  Loader</h2>
<div class="Halfloader"></div>
<h2>A 360 Loader | (Beta)</h2>
<div class="Fullloader"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
.Halfloader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  50% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.Fullloader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```css
.Halfloader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}


/* Safari */

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.Fullloader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>A 90 Loader</h2>
  <div class="Halfloader"></div>
  <h2>A 360 Loader | (Beta)</h2>
  <div class="Fullloader"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

output :

A 90 Loader 
spin with 90-degree as wanted 
A 360 Loader
spin with 90-degree but what I want is 360  degree

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I can see two loaders in one html page. Should your question be> How to Display Two or more Css animations in one html page?

Comment: Also, i see the animation going the 360% and comming back. Are you looking for a full infinit 360% animation?

Comment: i edited it and tried  to be more spefic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create one more keyframes for full rotation range 0 to 100%

```css
.Halfloader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes full {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes full {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


/* Safari */

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.Fullloader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  -webkit-animation: full 2s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: full 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>A 90 Loader</h2>
  <div class="Halfloader"></div>
  <h2>A 360 Loader | (Beta)</h2>
  <div class="Fullloader"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Work perfectly .Thanks